# Sort arrays, variables or objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, pdf, acrobat

Im new to javascript but I have already made some scripts that really make a difference in my workflow. However I am now embarking on a project that forces me to sort data in a way I dont know howto do in Javascript. I will try to explain what I need to do as if my data was in excel but it isnt, I have only been able to put the data in 4 different arrays:

```
 pagenumber[1,2,3,4,5] //only numbers
 zipcode[77889,99887,33667,11122,44559] // only numbers
 streetname[Hillroad, Hillroad, Baghdad Street, Hongway, Chinatown] //only letters
 roadnumber[55,27,1,13,16] //only numbers
```

I would like to sort them like this, first by the zipcode, then by the roadname, then by the even roadnumbers descending, then by the odd roadnumbers ascending.
According to this new sorting I want to generate a new pagenumber but I want it to somehow relate to the (old) variable "pagenumber" so I can locate the old page and extract it to a new document with new pagenumbers. I am not asking you guys to write all the code for me but I need a little bit of advice to know firstly if it is possible to do which I think it is, secondly if it is right of me to put the data in four different arrays, thirdly if ther is any (ofcourse) smarter way to save the data so they relate to eachother more closely. Give me your thoughts. Also tips of where and what I should read is appreciated. Thank you all for the answers. However I want to point out that I write my code in Acrobat DC not for the web.

Comment: what have you done so far in terms of sorting any of those arrays?? Please show us

Comment: I havent sorted it at all. Dont know howto. But I will!

Comment: if each index in each array refers to a single entity ... i.e. index 0 = 1, 77889, Hillroad, 55 etc, so when sorting one array you need to also reorder the other arrays, then you have about the least efficient way of storing your data that I could think of!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the items in your arrays are tied. So you should use `[{},{},{},{},{}]` instead of 4 arrays.

`var items = [{pagenumber:1,zipcode:77889,streetname:Hillroad,roadnumber:55},{...},{...},{...},{...}]`

Then sort each key-value property one-by-one, like below:

```
var x= [ {a:2,b:2,c:3}, {a:1,b:1,c:1}, {a:1,b:2,c:3}, {a:2,b:2,c:2} ];

x.sort(function(item1, item2){ 
    var sort_a = item1.a-item2.a;
    if (sort_a) return sort_a;
    var sort_b = item1.b-item2.b;
    if (sort_b) return sort_b;
    var sort_c = item1.c-item2.c;
    if (sort_c) return sort_c;
})
```

Or simplify it to be

```
x.sort(function(item1, item2){ 
    return (item1.a-item2.a) || (item1.b-item2.b) || (item1.c-item2.c);
})
```

Comment: how does this help with sorting strings like the streetname?

Comment: For strings use `item1.someStringKey.localCompare(item2.someStringKey)`.

Comment: @Xufox Cool method, I didn't think of string comparing.

Comment: should that be local**e**Compare

Answer (score 1):

Given the data:

```
var pagenumber=[1,2,3,4,5]; //only numbers
var zipcode=[77889,99887,33667,11122,44559]; // only numbers
var streetname=['Hillroad', 'Hillroad', 'Baghdad Street', 'Hongway', 'Chinatown']; //only letters
var roadnumber=[55,27,1,13,16]; //only numbers
```

First, you need to make your data more easily manageable

```
var data = pagenumber.map(function(itemValue, index) {
    return {
        pagenumber:itemValue, // == pagenumber[index]
        zipcode:zipcode[index],
        streetname:streetname[index],
        roadnumber:roadnumber[index]
    };
});
```

Then sort it

```
data.sort(function(a, b) {
     if (a.zipzode != b.zipcode) {
         // numeric
         return a.zipcode - b.zipcode;
     }
     if (a.streetname != b.streetname) {
         // alpha
         return a.streetname < b.streetname ? -1 : a.streetname > b.streetname ? 1 : 0;
     }
     if (a.roadnumber % 2 != b.roadnumber % 2) {
         // even before odd
         return b.roadnumber % 2 - a.roadnumber % 2;
     }
     // numeric
     return a.roadnumber - b.roadnumber;
});
```

borrowing from another answer, that can be simplified to

```
data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return  (a.zipcode - b.zipcode) || (a.streetname < b.streetname ? -1 : a.streetname > b.streetname ? 1 : 0) || (b.roadnumber % 2 - a.roadnumber % 2) || (a.roadnumber - b.roadnumber);
});
```

Personally, I don't use the intermediate step when I can avoid it ... so the following is equivalent to bot the map and sort in one chained command

```
var sortedData = pagenumber.map(function(itemValue, index) {
    return {
        pagenumber:itemValue, 
        zipcode:zipcode[index],
        streetname:streetname[index],
        roadnumber:roadnumber[index]
    };
}).sort(function(a, b) {
    return  (a.zipcode - b.zipcode) || (a.streetname < b.streetname ? -1 : a.streetname > b.streetname ? 1 : 0) || (b.roadnumber % 2 - a.roadnumber % 2) || (a.roadnumber - b.roadnumber);
});
```

Comment: Im trying to figure this out. Can you please tell me what val means?

Comment: sorry, let me rewrite that

Comment: If you read about [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) - see the part about the callback parameters - the callback to .map is called with arguments `(itemValue, index, array)` for each item in the array

Comment: Thank you very much for this information. I am gonna test it!

Comment: If I want to view the updated values after I ran the code, how do I do it. when I view the streetname and pagenumber variables they are as they were before I ran the code. Your code ran without errors. And secondly how does your code generate new pagenumbers?

Comment: `view the updated values` - where? in the console? in the browser? on your television? that's a very vague request. `how does your code generate new pagenumbers` - huh? it doesn't, it saves the original page numbers associated by position in the respective arrays

Comment: In the console, yes. How do I see the positions, I can view the arrays in the console but how can I then view the positions or access them when I ecxtract the pages. Sorry if you find my questions dumb.

Comment: the "positions" in an array are self evident ... the first item is in the first position

Comment: When I viev the pagenumber array before your code and after it is exactly the same, I thought I could see a difference. is it the sortedData variable I should check?

Comment: this code doesn't touch the original arrays, as they are, as I mentioned in the comment, possibly the least efficient way to store the data you have for what you want to do with it - i.e. manipulate the order. Each object in the final `sortedData` has the original `pagenumber` as a property of the object - this satisfies the part of your question where you want to "locate the old page" ... I'm pretty sure this answer has covered all bases of your original question

Comment: Thank you. Is this how I can view it: Object.keys(sortedData)?

Comment: console.dir(sortedData)

Comment: [object Object] is what I c

Comment: sorry, try `console.table(sortedData)` ... what browser are you using?

Comment: Im using acrobat javascript console window, i just type in the variable name

Comment: `acrobat javascript console window` - no idea what that is

Comment: Do this code read in my arrays or do I need to populate it within the loops I run to get the data?

Answer (score 0):

```
// sorting zipcode in ascending order
zipcode.sort();
// sorting streetname in ascending order
streetname.sort();
// fetching evenroad numbers
var roadnumbereven=roadnumber.filter(function(element, index, array) {
  return (element % 2 === 0);
});
// fetching odd roadnumbers
var roadnumberodd = roadnumber.filter(function(element, index, array) {
  return (element % 2 !== 0);
});
// sorting even road numbers in ascending order
roadnumbereven.sort();
// sorting odd road numbers in descending order
roadnumberodd.sort(function(a,b){ return b-a; });
// merging roadnumbers(even/odd)
roadnumber = roadnumbereven.concat(roadnumberodd);


console.log(roadnumber);
```